# Connection difference between protocol-delegate methods and block

Tags: ios, objective-c, connection, swift

i'm learning swift and found these protocol-delegate methods for connection:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
```

and 3 more... so they start as

```
connection.start()
```

But there are also block structure:

```
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

So difference with "sendAsynchronousRequest" i understand, but what's difference with this block method and what is a best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding both are  Asynchronous operation  .

Delegate Methods :
If you want to monitor the status of connection and recieveing data use delegate methods

Blocks:
If you dont want to monitor and only need to perform some operation when the data has been fully received use blocks .

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-SW1

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer! but can you give an example of process, that need to monitor ? download and then update UI needn't monitor, if i right ?

Comment: 1 . The delegate method can examine the provided NSURLResponse object and determine the expected content length of the data, MIME type, suggested filename, and other metadata provided by the server

Comment: use the connection:didReceiveData: method to provide an indication of the connection’s progress to the user.